# Potential race conditions when using iptables-persistent and fail2ban together?

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I'm using the `iptables` module `geoip` to only allow traffic from some countries and `fail2ban` in general to block scans.

I'm aware of fail2ban itself managing the persistence of its rules. Now I also want my geoip rules to be persistent, using `iptables-persistent`.

My (potential) problem: When `iptables-persistent` restores the rules it uses `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` without the `-n` option, which means that all existing rules will be overwritten.

I now fear race conditions on system startup where `fail2ban` is mid or finished restoring its rules an then `iptables-restore` overwrites everything.

Currently I've put the `-n` option to `/usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables` which will be called by `iptables-persistent` but modifying some scripts managed by the package is possible no good idea since it could be overwritten by an update.

Is there a safe or standard way to restore iptables rules without potential conflicts with the fail2ban service starting up? Or is it guaranteed that `iptables-restore` will run before the start of `fail2ban`?

Answer (score 1):

> Currently I've put the -n option

Sure, you can use `iptables-restore --noflush ...` to avoid removal of rules from fail2ban (or other services). Just be aware about the order of the rules (fail2ban would insert the rules before every other rules in INPUT chain, so if you have to pre-insert some other rules hereafter, use must do that with service dependencies).

> but modifying some scripts managed by the package is possible no good idea since it could be overwritten by an update.

Well, normally every service providing iptables rules, should manipulate only own rules and chains created by itself. If some service doing a complete flush of iptables during a runtime, I would say, that this is wrong conceptualized by design (and should be fixed).

> Or is it guaranteed that iptables-restore will run before the start of fail2ban?

You have to add a dependency for fail2ban service to guarantee that.

Or you can try to switch to some better net-filter (for instance `nftables`) using real tables. Just you could get the same issue if any service starting to flush the whole list (deleting every table) would do that somewhere in-between.